# Google console app bundle (Xamarin) upload problem

Tags: c#, android, xamarin.forms, google-developers-console

First of all, I want to say it's my first question.

I developed xamarin.forms application and now try to upload signed *abb* (generated visual studio 2019) google console.
But something went wrong.
Have any suggestions for that problem?

Error message

**Your Android App Bundle is signed with the wrong key. Ensure that your App Bundle is signed with the correct signing key and try again. Your App Bundle is expected to be signed with the certificate with fingerprint:**

**SHA1: 5C:DE:BE:BD:B6:FF:83:CF:14:86:58:87:CB:67:42:95:41:16:62:53**

**but the certificate used to sign the App Bundle you uploaded has fingerprint:**

**SHA1: 6C:1D:D3:0D:46:22:D5:1D:3A:9C:E2:D5:8A:C7:D4:D2:27:C0:94:E3**

Comment: Important: From August 2021, new apps are required to publish with the Android App Bundle on Google Play. New apps larger than 150 MB are now supported by either Play Feature Delivery or Play Asset Delivery.

Comment: this message seems pretty clear to me: "Your Android App Bundle is signed with the wrong key"

Comment: @Jason you are rights, but It's my initial release and I don't have any other key

Comment: [Google Play Console Help - Publishing Issues](https://support.google.com/googleplay/android-developer/answer/9061737?hl=en). See Issues with app signing or uploading. You might have to follow a link there to create a support ticket at Google. Be sure to mention that you are using Xamarin. If you created the signing key in Visual Studio, mention that too. Provide them with that error message, explain that this is the only key you have. They have a procedure for dealing with this. May take a few days.

Comment: Thanks all. Problem solved.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have the key which you generated for the first time, use it to submit .aab to Google, because Google took that key and already created certificate by that key. So if you don't have it, you should delete the app from Google and create a new one from scratch.

Comment: Thank you Ani, I'll try